# Error while creating the node

Tags: usb, serial

When I connect a UV projector to my raspberry I create two new nodes, /hidraw0 and /usb.

Although the projector isn't responding because the node should be a serial lilke /ttyUSB*.

Can I get any help about why I'm getting the wrong node and about how to fix it?

Thanks!!

Comment: How do you create the two new nodes? Do you need a driver to connect the projector?

Comment: Where should I install the driver?

I also thought it can be a problem of a driver... I don't know if I need one